# Why can't I ping a network printer from a specific computer only on the same network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing

I have a small home network with a few computers/tablets and a network-enabled printer, all connected through wifi. The problem is I cannot connect (ping) from one specific computer ("A", 192.168.8.101) to the network printer (192.168.8.25), while at the same time all other computers can. Specifically:

- this seems to be a network/routing problem, as pinging the printer from "A" gives me a "destination host not reachable" error message
- from any other computer/tablet, pinging the printer works, and it is also possible to browse to the printer's built-in webserver and print
- pinging any other computer from "A" works, web connectivity is OK as well
- routing tables ("route print") are identical on "A" and other machines (see below)
- "arp -a" does NOT show the printer's IP-address on "A", but does so on other machines.

I have already tried:

- turning firewall off on "A" (there is no anti-virus software installed)
- adding a static route to the printer
- disabling all other network adapters except the wifi adapter
- adding a static ARP entry using "netsh" command (this results in a "request timed out" error message, rather than "destination host not reachable", when pinging)
- changing the IP address of the printer
- using a static IP address for the printer.

Nothing has helped so far. Computer "A" is the only one running Windows 8.1. I do not know if this affects routing and/or address resolution.

I wonder what I could do next in order to troubleshoot the problem. Are there any settings in the OS that would explain this phenomenon?

Output of "ipconfig /all":

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ComputerA
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 19:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 86-3A-4B-47-E1-31
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 86-3A-4B-47-E1-30
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 84-3A-4B-47-E1-31
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-90-D1-D8
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::38dc:b59e:3191:6515%9(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.80.80(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 939529565
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-28-15-BC-84-3A-4B-47-E1-30
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 84-3A-4B-47-E1-30
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F4-B7-E2-CE-86-09
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Mobile Broadband adapter Mobile broadband:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Ericsson C5621 gw
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 94-9B-B5-5F-5C-43
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 84-3A-4B-47-E1-30
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d14a:e704:f11f:5501%3(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.101(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Freitag, 27. Dezember 2013 12:30:54
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Samstag, 28. Dezember 2013 12:30:55
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 260323915
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-28-15-BC-84-3A-4B-47-E1-30
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 195.34.133.21
                                       212.186.211.21
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{97C67FE7-5E1A-4399-AB63-C0F08A323E68}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{1540CEC9-29E7-481C-9389-D54017341EBE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #11
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Output of "route print":

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 37...86 3a 4b 47 e1 31 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 27...86 3a 4b 47 e1 30 ......Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
 26...84 3a 4b 47 e1 31 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
  9...00 15 5d 90 d1 d8 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
  8...84 3a 4b 47 e1 30 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
  6...f4 b7 e2 ce 86 09 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  4...94 9b b5 5f 5c 43 ......Ericsson C5621 gw
  3...84 3a 4b 47 e1 30 ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #9
 22...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #11
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.8.1    192.168.8.101     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     169.254.80.80    261
    169.254.80.80  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.80.80    261
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.80.80    261
      192.168.8.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.8.101    281
    192.168.8.101  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.8.101    281
    192.168.8.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.8.101    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     169.254.80.80    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.8.101    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.80.80    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.8.101    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  9    261 fe80::/64                On-link
  3    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    261 fe80::38dc:b59e:3191:6515/128
                                    On-link
  3    281 fe80::d14a:e704:f11f:5501/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
  9    261 ff00::/8                 On-link
  3    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Output of "arp -a":

```
Interface: 192.168.8.101 --- 0x3
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.8.1           44-32-c8-74-d8-b1     dynamic   
  192.168.8.2           10-bf-48-d3-5d-40     dynamic   
  192.168.8.20          00-08-9b-be-2c-74     dynamic   
  192.168.8.123         00-1f-3c-b1-82-1d     dynamic   
  192.168.8.200         00-0e-58-28-e6-b8     dynamic   
  192.168.8.205         00-0e-58-f3-36-8c     dynamic   
  192.168.8.206         00-0e-58-67-17-18     dynamic   
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static    
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static    
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static    
  224.0.1.60            01-00-5e-00-01-3c     static    
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static    
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static    

Interface: 169.254.80.80 --- 0x9
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  169.254.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static    
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static    
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static    
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static    
  224.0.1.60            01-00-5e-00-01-3c     static    
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
```

Comment: Can the Win8 computer see the other computers on the network? Also, do you have network discovery turned on?

Comment: Yes, other computers can be pinged, and network discovery is on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of research on the web, I found a partial solution to the problem. It seems that this particular network printer (HP OfficeJet 8500 pro) does have a problem if there is also a 5 GHz network present. I turned it off on the router, and it suddenly works (I can ping and print from all computers).

However, this does not explain why previously it was only not possible to ping from computer A, but it worked from all other computers. Also, for future reference, I'd like to know how to further troubleshoot this kind of problems... any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: This also did the trick for my Epson WF-3520.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the real problem is that Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3 is taking priority over WiFi and ping is getting lost inside virtual network. You should try to disable Ethernet 3 and try again.

Comment: Computer A uses DHCP, so it does not have a static IP address. Running the commands did not help either. Also, other computers can ping computer A, so it doesn't look like an address conflict to me.

Comment: Interesting, but DHCP is definitely activated... also, on the router (DHCP server), it lists computer A with dynamic DHCP address.

Comment: I had tried disabling other network adapters before (see post), but to no avail. Also, I have changed the priority order of adapters such that wifi is on top, no change. What I really wonder is: why can I ping other computers on the same network just fine? 192.168.8.20 for example is a NAS, and I can perfectly ping it, mount network shares etc.

Comment: Do you know of any other tool that might help here? Wireshark?

Comment: you need to run `tracert 192.168.8.25` command to see what route it is taking.

Comment: tracert only returns "* * * destination host unreachable" messages...