# Cannot ping printer from computers, can from router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printer

I have a wireless home network set up with multiple devices (computers running Windows 7 and 10, smart phones, etc.) and an HP 8600 printer.  Two days ago, I also received a new router from my ISP which I set up.

At first, I was having difficulties printing from the computers ( as per https://superuser.com/a/694973/270090 ) but everything was set up and working yesterday.

This morning when I woke up, none of the computers could print to the printer.

I have tried all the basics (reconnecting the printer to the network, rebooting the printer, reconnecting the computers to the network, disabling various firewalls, etc.) but nothing has helped.

I can ping the router from the computers and I can ping both the printer and the computers from the router but I can't ping the printer from the computers.  I have also tried running `arp -v -a` from the Windows 10 computer and I see

```
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.0.101         00-00-00-00-00-00     invalid
```

but trying to delete the record or add a new one has no effect.

As a final point which may or may not be relevant, starting this morning, all the Windows 7 computers are exhibiting an issue where an extra number is appended to their SSID like so:

[image]

Comment: *I can ping the router from the computers and I can ping both the printer and the computers from the router but I can't ping the printer from the computers.* ... and no ping between 2 computers, is it? I think that your router is set in isolated mode - i.e. it does not allow the connections between clients. Look for such setting and disable it.

Comment: Yes, I can't ping any one computer from any other (though I can ping them all from the router).  However, as far as I can tell, the router doesn't have an isolation mode.  Or at least, searching for `isol` in the user manual doesn't turn up anything ftp://ftp2.zyxel.com/EMG2926-Q10A/user_guide/EMG2926-Q10A_1.00.pdf

Comment: I do see a setting "Intra-BSS Traffic blocking" but it's disabled, if that's relevant.